# How to use the stuff commands the right way?

Tags: sql-server

i've been reading some documents about the STUFF command but when im trying to concatenate some results in only one row with the STUFF command it's not working as i expected, what am i doing wrong?

```
select 
    u.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA,
    u.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA,

    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + DSC_PRODUTO
    FROM PRODUTO PRO WHERE P.COD_PRODUTO = PRO.COD_PRODUTO 
    order by DSC_PRODUTO
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
    [Produtos]

from UNIDADE_VENDA u
join PRECO p 
    on u.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = p.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
join PRODUTO PRO
    on p.COD_PRODUTO = pro.COD_PRODUTO

    where DAT_FINAL_VIGENCIA > '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000'
  --group by u.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA
    order by u.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA asc
```

Results are comming this way for the Produtos Column : product1 \n product2 \n product3... instead of p13, p45, p20...

Comment: From what you posted it is impossible to provide an answer. This is because you didn't provide enough information. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What do you mean by "in only one row"? That's a correlated subquery. And you just want to strip out the first character?

Comment: What is your input and your expected output?

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry. i was a little busy at the momment, what i'm trying to say is that the query is bringing me the result in this way:

revendor1 l product 1
revendor1 l product 2
revendor1 l product 3
revendor2 l product 2
revendor2 l product 4

Instead of that i want the query to bring me the result this way :

revendor1 l product1, product2, product3
revendor2 l product2, product4
revendor3 l product1, product3, product4

Sorry by the lack of information that i provided before! and thank's for the answers, its my first time using stackoverflow :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iOQNk.png results how it should be